# how to keep the previous images when calling matplotlib imshow() multiple times in a single cell google colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, imshow

I wanted to show multiple images in a single cell of google colab using maltplotlib imshow()

When it is used only once in a cell, the image will be shown.

But when multiple imshow() fcalls are made , the previous imshow()s outputs are cleared .

```
wkwk=test("face18.jpg")
#jst for face
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
top, right, bottom, left =face_locations[0]
sus_face = image[top:bottom, left:right]

plt.imshow(wkwk)
plt.imshow(sus_face)
```

*here only sus_face is shown & wkwk image is not*

is there any way to see both images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `plt.show()` after each of your `plt.imshow(image)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with subplots like this:

```
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(name_of_var)
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(another_var)
```

Comment: here what is 121 ,122?

Comment: These define the position of different `subplots`, could also be written as `(1,2,1)` etc. just like in `matlab`. Read more at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot